# Magento how to cache a productCollection

Tags: magento, caching, apc

Ive noticed my home page is taking a long time to load - over 6 seconds infact according site24x7.com, so ive been switching elements off to try and determine what is the cause, and it is down to 2 product collection files I have made to show new products and best selling products.

As soon as i remove these from the home page, the page loads in less than .5 seconds.

So, can anyone help with optimising and caching a productCollection?  I have APC installed and running on the server, but Im not sure it is caching the files located in app/design/frontend/default/MY_THEME/catalog/product/newproducts.phtml

So, my collection call for best selling (most viewed actually) looks like this;

```
    <?php $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); // return current store id  ?>
    <?php $_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount()
    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(8)
    ?>
```

How can I further optimise this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
  $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 
  $cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache');
  $key = 'homepage-most-view-' . $storeId;

  if(! $data = $cache->load($key)){
      $_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
      ->addViewsCount()
      ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
      ->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
      $_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(8)
      // get the element you need from  $_productCollection and store in $array
      $data = serialize($array);
      $cache->save(urlencode($data), $key, array("homepage_cache"), 60*60*24);
  }
  else{
      $data = unserialize(urldecode($data)); 
 }
```

See

- http://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/
- http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-block-caching/

Comment: @R.S Why do you use `urlencode` twice? Is it necessary or is it a bug here? Shouldn't this be: `$data = urlencode(serialize($array));
$cache->save($data, $key, array("homepage_cache"), 60*60*24);` ?

Comment: It was a typo.. fixed now

Comment: Mage::app()->getCache() instead of Mage::getSingleton('core/cache') can save you a lot of time...

Comment: Why are you url encoding at all?

Comment: I'm also seeing that I am unable to cache a product collection. I guess why that's you are storing it into an array. Does magento prevent serializing product collections because they are too large?

Comment: Not working, not getting product collection after getcache

Answer (score 5):

If you want to cache $collection, there is already a built-in possibility for collection caching in Magento.

```
 $_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');

$cache = Mage::app()->getCache(); //Let's get cache instance
        $cache->setLifetime(86400); //Here we set collection cache lifetime
        $_productCollection->initCache(
            $cache,
            'Bestsellers_', //this is just custom prefix
            array('collections') 
        );
    }
```

Credit for above code: apiworks.net (http://www.apiworks.net/2015/01/magento-collection-caching.html)

Comment: in this example I understand how top set it. But is there logic we need to implement the 2nd run to check if a cache exists and only then save it to cache ... or does "cache know/do this of there own"  thhx!

Comment: Hi,@snh_nl. As you can see in the following code , which is part of Varien_Data_Collection_Db class: http://collabshot.com/show/H0q3bn
Magento tries to load from the cache first and then if fails, it loads from database and saves the cached version. 
So, the answer is: for the same $collection object, you don't need to do anything else once you initialised the cache using the code above. It will automatically load next time for you.

Comment: Could we use the code like this https://gist.github.com/seansan/1397a892fa496d5b5f98c2d85e4fa82e in a html template file? Or how would one cache a collection call in a phtml file (for instance product listing)